# Celery and Django, Logging Celery

Tags: django, nginx, virtualenv, celery, django-celery

I'm running celery with django and works great in development. But now I want to make it live 
on my production server and I am running into some issues.

My setup is as follows:

- Ubuntu
- Nginx
- Vitualenv
- Upstart
- Gunicorn
- Django

I'm not sure how to now start celery with django when starting it with upstart and where does it log to?

Im starting django here:

```
~$ cd /var/www/webapps/minamobime_app
~$ source ../bin/activate
```

> exec /var/www/webapps/bin/gunicorn_django -w $NUM_WORKERS \
>           --user=$USER --group=$GROUP --bind=$IP:$PORT --log-level=debug \
>           --log-file=$LOGFILE 2>>$LOGFILE

how do I start celery?

```
exec python manage.py celeryd -E -l info -c 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider configuring celery as a [daemon](http://ask.github.com/celery/cookbook/daemonizing.html). For logging speciy:

> CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n.log"

where %s will be replaced by the node name

Comment: How am i supposed to start celery with upstart just for this questions regard. currently i have it like this:exec /var/www/webapps/bin/gunicorn_django -w $NUM_WORKERS \
    --user=$USER --group=$GROUP --bind=$IP:$PORT --log-level=debug \
    --log-file=$LOGFILE 2>>$LOGFILE
exec python manage.py celeryd -E -l info -c 2

Answer (score 2):

You can install **supervisor** using apt-get and then you can add the following to a file named celeryd.conf (or any name you wish) to etc/supervisor/conf.d folder (create the conf.d folder if it is not present)

```
; ==================================
;  celery worker supervisor example
; ==================================

[program:celery]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=/home/<path to env>/env/bin/celery -A <appname> worker -l info
;enter the directory in which you want to run the app
directory=/home/<path to the app> 
user=nobody
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/<path to the log file>/worker.log
stderr_logfile=/home/<path to the log file>/worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 1000

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998
```

Also add the following lines to etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf

```
[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

Now start the supervisor by typing supervisord in terminal and celery will start automatically according to the settings you made above.

Comment: You can also add django and other programs to supervisord to start them automatically. You can visit http://supervisord.org/ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can run:

```
python manage.py celery worker
```

this will work if you have `djcelery` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`